# Out of memory exception in System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bitmap, out-of-memory, system.drawing

I need to resize file upload image/images in 3 different sizes (each of them), and save their paths into the database.

I wrote belove method for this.

```
public void resize(string tempPath,string fname,string extension,int x,int y,string path) {

          System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(tempPath);

            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Bitmap tnBitmap = new Bitmap(img);
                Graphics tnGraph = Graphics.FromImage(tnBitmap);
                tnGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                //settings ..
                double ratioX = (double)x / (double)tnBitmap.Width;
                double ratioY = (double)y / (double)tnBitmap.Height;
                double ratio = ratioX < ratioY ? ratioX : ratioY;
                int newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(tnBitmap.Height * ratio);
                int newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(tnBitmap.Width * ratio);    
                int posX = Convert.ToInt32((x - (tnBitmap.Width * ratio)) / 2);
                int posY = Convert.ToInt32((y - (tnBitmap.Height * ratio)) / 2);
                tnGraph.DrawImage(img, posX, posY, newWidth, newHeight);    
                img.Dispose();
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {                      
                    tnBitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    fs.Close();
                    try
                    {
                        FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.address.com/httpdocs/img-cdn" + @"\" + fname + extension);    
                        req.UseBinary = true;
                        req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pw");
                        StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(memory);

                        rdr.Close();
                        req.ContentLength = memory.ToArray().Length;

                        Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();

                        reqStream.Write(memory.ToArray(), 0, memory.ToArray().Length);
                        reqStream.Close();
                    }
                    catch (WebException e)
                    {
                        String status = ((FtpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription;
                    }                       
                    path = "www.address.com/" + fname + extension;
                }
                memory.Dispose();
                tnBitmap.Dispose();
                tnGraph.Dispose();    
            }
```

}

Method calls:

```
public ActionResult addPathFu(string ID){
     List<ProductImage> lPi = new List<ProductImage>();
     string mTempPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
     string sTempPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
     string bTempPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
     string extension = "";
     for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
     {            
          ProductImage pi = new ProductImage();
          //bigPath file 
          var bigFileName = $@"{DateTime.Now.Ticks}-b";
          extension = Path.GetExtension(Request.Files[i].FileName);
          Request.Files[i].SaveAs(bTempPath);              
          resize(bTempPath,bigFileName,extension,1500,1500,pi.BigPath);

          //midpath 
          var midFileName = $@"{DateTime.Now.Ticks}-m";
          extension=Path.GetExtension(Request.Files[i].FileName);
          resize(mTempPath, midFileName, extension, 500, 750,pi.MidPath);

          Request.Files[i].SaveAs(mTempPath);

          //smallpath
          var sFileName = $@"{DateTime.Now.Ticks}-s";
          extension = Path.GetExtension(Request.Files[i].FileName);
          Request.Files[i].SaveAs(sTempPath);
          resize(sTempPath, sFileName, extension, 295, 443,pi.SmallPath);

          lPi.Add(pi);
     }
  }
```

The problem is, second time I call this method in runtime,  `System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(tempPath);` statement throws error:

> Out of Memory Exception.

I disposed everything that is disposable. Also I enabled in web.config :

```
<runtime>
  <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
</runtime>
```

Do I use too much memory? How can I fix this?

Comment: OOM in FromFile() can often (misleadingly) indicate a problem with the source file format so double check its a valid image file.

Comment: FromFile() takes file from C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpB4C3.tmp, I checked the source file it exists @AlexK.

Comment: You have `Image img` as a method parameter and then `System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(tempPath);` in the method body. This wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake while copy pasting. I updated my question  @Jimi

Comment: @Zeynep please check if the file is a valid image - regarding its file type, not if the path is correct. If `Image.FromFile(string path)` can not find that file, an `FileNotFoundException` would be thrown. Could you try another image, from a folder you won't get trouble with user access?

Comment: Method call: `resize(bTempPath,bigFileName,extension,1500,1500,pi.BigPath);`. Is `1500,1500` the new size of the image? If so, you just need to build a Bitmap this size and draw in it the source Bitmap using a destination Rectangle sized using these new measures.  Never ever use a Bitmap directly loaded from a file. Change it in something like this: `Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(tempPath).Clone();`. Or, `Bitmap newBitmap; using (Image img = Image.FromFile(tempPath)) { newBitmap = (Bitmap)img.Clone(); }`. Otherwise, GDi+ will hold a handle on that image.

Comment: @nilsK Yes, the problem is about file temporary images. So I use just one temporary file `string TempPath = Path.GetTempFileName();`  it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

too many 'path' in your routine declare, perharps shorten it like:

```
public void resize(string tempPath, string fname, string extension, int x, int y, string path, Image img)
```

You just edited

Comment: This method declaration does not reflect the code currently in the question. Also, it's not the problem.

Comment: His original code was wrong,  but then as soon as I posted, he corrected his. THAT IS WHY I edit my post and said "You just edited"